# How get coefs name from glmnet in R?

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am doing lasso with `glmnet` in R. I have the lasso coefs `out$beta`

Input:

```
x1  0.5744207722
x2 -0.3575682570
x3 -0.0995794334
```

How can I extract the name of the variables?

Desired output:
`x1, x2,x3`

What I tried

1. `$`
2. `as.data.frame`
3. `as.matrix`

but none of them convert the `coefs` into a n row 2 columns matrix. They remain as a vector, `x1  0.5744207722`.

I cannot do it manually. I have more than 1000 variables and more models to run. And I don't won't to write it on my disk, and read it back.

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `glmnet`?  The very first example shows you how to pull out the coefficients for each variable using `coef()`.

Comment: I want names `x1`, `x2` not coefs `0.5744207722`, `-0.3575682570`

Comment: Then `rownames(coef(fit))`.  If that doesn't do what you want, give a reproducible example with inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: If you try yourself, it would return `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. The question has been revised.

Comment: The reason is glmnet returns a vector rather than a matrix or data frame.

Comment: `rownames(out$beta)` Doesn't work?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Works! Thanks!!!

Comment: @alex23lemm Please move the comment to the answer section. Will accept it. Very useful. Very practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your input above it seems that you specified a `glmnet` call with a single lambda value.

In this particular case you can extract the names of the coefficients like this: `names(out$beta[, 1][out$beta[, 1] != 0])`. Please note that only the names of the non-zero betas are extracted, which makes sense when applying Lasso here since Lasso performs feature reduction.

A minimum reproducible example would be this: 
`out <- glmnet(as.matrix(mtcars[-1]), mtcars[["mpg"]], lambda = 1)`